# Can burnout happen when doing Scrum sprints continuously?

Tags: agile, scrum, development-process

I'm with a pretty small startup and we started using a form of a Scrum/Agile development cycle.

In many ways I enjoy Scrum.  We have relatively short sprints (2 weeks) and I like the Burn Down Chart to track the team's progress. I also like the Feature Board so I always know what I should be doing next.  It feels good taking down a feature's card from the board, completing it and then putting it in the burn down pile.

However, we are now entering in our 18th Sprint release cycle and I'm starting to feel a little burnt out.  It isn't that I don't like job or my co-workers, it is just that these sprints are... well, *sprints*.  From start to finish I literally feel like I'm racing against the clock to maintain our development velocity.  When we are done with the sprint we spend one day planning the next sprint's feature set and estimates and then off we go again.

For people who work in a mature Agile/Scrum development process, is this normal?  Or are we missing something?  Is there normally time in a Scrum enviornment that is unassigned/untracked to get done some minor things and to clear your head?

Comment: I'd take a closer look at the content of the sprint more than the methodology. Pure development (no testing, spikes, code reviews) can kill people after a while. Also, the scrum master should be defending the team against unreasonable roadmaps, time estimations from the team etc. During availability calculation, make sure you account for 10-20% non-committed times to account for unscheduled meetings, bathroom breaks, distractions, etc. Then plan for any and everything during ceremonies. It all balances out in the end.

Comment: if this is not constructive, where in the Stackexchange ecosystem would it best be located?

Comment: Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com ...not sure.

Comment: Question with 53 upvotes. Accepted answer with 49. Closed as not constructive. Clearly some self-righteous "moderators" have stopped taking their medication. Again.

Comment: Agree, the question is around requirements for capacity planning and so is the selected answer

Comment: Some of your sprints should be "meta": developing a new testing framework for future sprints, or building a demo for a new algorithm, or a "refactoring sprint" to clean up dead and spaghetti code .... or even (we did this) a "sprint" oriented around producing a really cool powerpoint presentation (i did the graphs in R).   You need to break things up.   Sometimes "shippable" doesn't have to mean "compiled code".

Comment: Burnout can happen. The important bit is how do you avoid burnout before it's too late. For software engineer this post might help https://usehaystack.io/blog/post/using-git-signals-to-identify-burnout/

Comment: @SzG Yes, some moderators' mood may be a limitation overall of Stack Exchange. But it also has a solution. Flag the question to re-open (I just flagged). Overall nobody is perfect but the overall community can move things forward. Thank you 95% of the moderators!!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is relatively normal and can sometimes be a complaint of our team members if projects continue for a long period of time.

The key to what we're talking about here is *sustainable pace*. If you and your team are able to sustain your pace over the long term, that's excellent -- you've achieve the hyperproductivity that all Scrum teams are striving for.

Alternatively, if you're finding that you overestimate how much work you can actually get done in a day, then you may need to reevaluate that during your retrospective. The amount of productive time in a day that a team chooses to recognize when doing their capacity planning for a sprint is referred to as a **focus factor**.

Henrik Kniberg has this to say:

> The “default” focus factor I use for
>   new teams is usually 70%, since that
>   is where most of our other teams have
>   ended up over time.
>
> http://www.crisp.se/henrik.kniberg/ScrumAndXpFromTheTrenches.pdf

However, what it sounds like you're talking about is simply the nonstop momentum of sprint after sprint, not necessarily your productivity in a day. Here's some suggestions of things we have tried to deal with that:

- End the sprint on a Friday morning. Have your sprint review and retrospective in the morning and let the team work on something else the rest of the day to clear their heads. Pick up with Sprint planning on Monday.
- We introduced the notion of "lab days". These are entire days that the team is taken away from the project and they spend the day working on improving their own technical skills through research with each other and collaboration on specific technical topics. Most of the time they have absolutely nothing to do with the specific project and allow team members to think about lighter topics.

Comment: Kniberg said himself: "focus factor is one of the things I'd like to rip out of the book. Stopped using it right after writing the book..." — https://twitter.com/henrikkniberg/status/207853426967715841

Answer (score 26):

From Wikipedia on burnout: "burnout is largely an organizational issue caused by long hours, little down time, and continual peer, customer, and superior surveillance"

They might as well have an icon image of Scrum next to the definition of burnout.

If you think you can send someone onto something else for a brief diversion to fix burnout, you obviously haven't thought it through. Ever go on a vacation after being burned out and go back to work thinking, Wow! Now I'm refreshed and ready for another 6 months of this torture until I finally get a break again. Nope, what happens is you realize, Wow! My job sucks. Now I can really see how my stupid manager's micro-managing, development process is just another way of getting more out of me for less and life's too short for this... I should find something else to do or change jobs to something less stressful.

IMHO, short 2 weeks Scrum should be prohibited except in small doses, not more than 4-8 in a row. Use it as a tool for exceptional or critical things, not continually. Use common sense.

Comment: This is ridiculous FUD, Scrum is certainly not about having people get burned out, short sprint are not about working 80 per week.

Comment: Sorry to chime in so late.  But exactly.

Comment: In my opinion, Scrum actually reduces my chances for a burnout. Just because the team is self-organising and self-managing, the team is responsible for the estimates and the work it plans for the sprint. I don't miss the days where 'managers' prioritized their demands above anyone else. Or where 'managers' asked me to do 'this little thing' for them.
Also, Scrum defines a normal work day should be 7 to 8 hours for a 'developer' and no one should 'manage' the team or track the team's progress (except for the team itself).
Scrum forces the 'managers' (aka stakeholders) to really prioritize.

Comment: This is right on the mark. It's funny how the scrum lovers defend it with the fairy tale of how it's 'supposed' to be done, but most developers experience just what the OP talks about.

Comment: I've realised this over the last couple of years and agree completely with what's been said here.  I'm desperate to get out of working like this even if it might mean being a bum for a while and using savings. Not to mention the dreaded 'stand up' every morning. I wake up and wish I was anywhere else, and I'm working on making that a reality.

Comment: For me, scrum causes burnout.  The number of hours I work and the amount of productivity I have doesn't change, but my mood does.  Without scrum, I got work done and felt good doing it.  When we added the scrum process, I got the same work done at the same pace, but constantly fretted over the deadlines and meetings, so I no longer enjoyed it.  Not enjoying your work is the pathway to quitting.  Also, the burn-down chart can be an amazing demotivator when a sprint is going poorly.

Comment: I want to say that there is a wide variety of difference between the companies I"ve seen use the term scrum.  For the purest orgs, Scrum means they fix their deliverables, deliver on time, and do a lot of planning to make sure it works out that way.  For the least pure orgs, Scrum means you're expected to deliver every two weeks, the requirements are constantly in flux, and you get a micromanagement meeting every morning.  I'd say that the latter version of scrum happens more often than the former, and causes the burnout described above much faster.

Comment: They call it the Scrum "burndown" for a reason. It turns out it's more than the chart that's burning.

Answer (score 13):

You’re getting worn out after 36 weeks of hard work; that’s not Scrum, that’s human nature! Scrum is not there to make you work harder, it’s there to help you work more consistently and with greater predictability. I often see people confusing the symptoms of normal project management with what they perceive are symptoms of agile methodologies (i.e. “the customer keeps changing requirements – it must be Scrum’s fault!”). It’s an important distinction though because without identifying the cause you can’t treat the symptoms. Personally I’d be looking at ways to reduce burnout such as stress management techniques. There’s heaps of info out there on how to succeed in a stressful environment.

Comment: "Personally I’d be looking at ways to reduce burnout such as stress management techniques" - In other words "There's nothing wrong with our process, you're doing it wrong, if you're burned out and stressed the problem is with you and you need to learn to deal with it..."  All scrum evangelists....  who are in fact a massive part of the problem.

Answer (score 13):

The team that I am currently working on solves this problem really nicely. After three sprints we have a week in which each developer may work on what he wants. Those side projects should be linked to business value, but there is no pressure to get it done. It is a measure to allow us developers to explore new technologies, but it also provides us with a week of more relaxed, fun work.

This for sure helps me to not get burned out.

Answer (score 11):

No matter what development process you're using, if the team is getting burned out something is wrong.  It may be as simple as people not taking the vacation time they need, or it could be in the details of how you handle your scrums.  Teams are effective over the long-term because everyone gets the rest they need along the way.

Answer (score 10):

A Sprint is not a 100 yard dash; it is one (random) mile in a marathon, i.e. a pace that you can sustain indefinitely.

Is your Team conducting retrospectives at the end of each Sprint?  This is the Team's opportunity to "inspect and adapt" their process?  As a ScrumMaster, I regularly ask the Team to rate how the Team as an entity 'feels', and if they're having fun.  We explore why or why not, and experiment with adjustments and alternatives.

In my experience, Team members enjoy (up to a limit) the 'pressure' that the Sprint timebox constrains.  The key is to approach, but not exceed, that zone.  As needed, calibrating that zone is a prime checkpoint in a retrospective.

As for "... time in a Scrum environment that is unassigned/untracked to get done some minor things and to clear your head", keeping the Team commitment at x% of the available capacity (points, preferably, but hours can be used if needed; in either case I've found something in the range of 60-70% seems the norm) is key to sustainability inside of a Sprint, and an occasional 'free code day' works well for outside Sprints.

Comment: Maybe they shouldn't call it a Sprint then, eh?  They should call it a Lap.

Comment: I'm convinced they call it a Sprint to keep people outside the team from interfering. A Sprint sounds like something you shouldn't interrupt.

Comment: A lap implies no goal, its just one of many more, a sprint defines a 'run to a goal' which a `sprint` ultimately is. The terminology is sound IMHO

Comment: Just use "iteration".  To most of us, the terms are synonymous already, but "iteration" lacks the whole "run until you drop dead of exhaustion" connotation.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to reduce the number of hours in the day spent on the sprint.

I know some people whose workdays consisted of a mere two and a half hour of sprint, with the remainder of the day focused on a variety of other activities: support, relieving technical debt, research, etc.. Their development velocity was set accordingly.

That may seem a bit extreme, but if I'm not mistaken it was a profitable company until the recent widespread economic shock hit.

Comment: I think right now we are set at 6 hours of sprint per day.  Maybe that is just a little too much.

Comment: It may not sound like a lot, but I find that it is a pretty tight rope to walk.  If no real issues come up during the day you can maintain it fine, but if you hit a snag it destroys your velocity for that day.

Comment: My team does planning on the basis of 5 productive hours per day. And TBH I think that 4.5 hours would probably suit us better.  So I think that 6 productive hours per day *is* a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You are in your 18th sprint!?

Considering 2 weeks per sprint, that means 36 weeks nonstop working on the same project. You also comment that work around 6 hours each day. That sounds like a lot!

I don't know that much about agile methodologies (although we're actually using Scrum in our current project), but there's a principle about your working hours (I mean, the amount of time you spend doing a task) should be 60%~70%. Now, doing numbers again, if your labor day is 8 hours long, and you spend 6 hours working, you're really spending around 75% of your labor time. This could be a little deviation that has finally make you have that feeling.

OTOH, I believe that if your project will take long time to be done, sprints should be larger, not 2 weeks, but not a month. Consider a downward curve on your burnout chart: Start your sprint with a regular task burn, and reduce your activity on the last 2 or 3 days before the sprint ends.

Agile is not a stone with the engraving:"work faster/stronger/better/harder", it's more like a blue sky with white clouds that read:"work nice, beautiful more productive". (a little lol at the end courtesy of daft punk + radiohead).

Answer (score 6):

I fully understand what you are saying. For those of you that say "your pace is too fast," I'm not sure I agree that pace is always the problem when people get burned out by this process. Even though keeping track of all your progress IS a good thing, it can also be a stress factor itself (and not keeping track can be as well), not just because your boss/PM will be on you if they see something is not going according to plan, but for yourself. Just having this logged info is something that WILL make most people work just that little bit harder than you normally would ALL THE TIME and I'm not sure putting more time on your time estimates will fix this for everyone. I don't think a motivator (like your burn down chart) is always positive.

Some people won't feel this way, others will. There is not ONE way of work that WILL fit all. Never will be, in my opinion.

Also, if you say that these agile methods and sprints are not becoming more effective/productive, why are you using it at all? Why do you think companies want to use these methods at all? It's not because they are fun....

Effectiveness/productivity always comes at some type of price, in my opinion. It doesn't pop up from nowhere just by using the magic methods (if you get my point).

The only way for you to become more effective (work and pressure-wise) and do less work is make someone else do the work or by automating it.

In my opinion, one should always review ones processes and see what can be automated and spend time on automating your processes instead. Automation comes at the price of doing extra work instead of doing "the real work" but no matter how small the automated task you will always profit in the long run. ALWAYS! If not one day, in two. Not one month, two. Not one year, in two years. You get the idea.

However, I like the idea of having time off to work on personal projects. Most companies will never allow this though. But perhaps you can persuade your employer to get this time to automate your processes and this work could be "outside of sprint control" to allow the time you are talking about to "rest" and get energy back for a new sprint.

Those were just my 2 cents. I get a bit frightened when people say these methods aren't here to make us more effective and work harder. Of course they are! When you have no trace of what you are doing you will rest when your body tells you to. When "everything" you do is traced, you will push yourself. Or I correct myself, most people work this way, some will rest anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sustainable pace is a key tenet of agile. When doing the management (SCRUM) practices along with the engineering (XP) practices, a team can deliver sprint after sprint indefinitely. However, because one can does not mean one should.

It sounds like you need a change against the endless string of sprints you see ahead of you. A number of options can be offered. Every X number of sprints, a team member (or pair) can rotate off of a team. During your rotation, you can support the run team, take a class, focus on a set of spikes, take vacation etc.

If the team has 5 pairs, and you rotate a person off the line, A person could take an off rotation every 10th sprint (if a single person) or every 5th iteration (if a pair). Issues of budget and return on investment for your activities will need to be addressed by your leadership and or business partner. But clearly, having some time to "sharpen the saw" would bring benefit to the team thus the project. Keeping the team fresh and focused is a very good thing. But we must remember, we are getting paid and we need to bring value for the dollars we earn.

Comment: Maybe they shouldn't call it a Sprint then, eh? They should call it a Lap.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing something, but you are not the only one. As Jim Highsmith says: *“Velocity is increasingly being used as a productivity measure (not the capacity calibration measure that it was intended to be) that focuses too much attention on the volume of story points delivered.”*

I’d guess that is what is happening to your team. I recommend reading this Highsmith’s IMHO seminal post: [Velocity is Killing Agility!](http://jimhighsmith.com/velocity-is-killing-agility/)